# How to mange c++ object from java

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Is it possible to run c++ code form java?

I have c++ code that is able to stream RTP packets to a given ip and port.
this class has 2 method, `startRTP()` and `stopRTPO()` and a `constructor(String ip, int port)`

Is it possible somehow to use the dll in java, create an object and invoke these methods ?

Comment: Sure. Take a look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface for a start. You will find plenty of examples when looking for "java native"

Comment: Another (maybe simpler) solution is to use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access